# Weird value of System.getProperty("os.name")

Tags: java

Im trying to get the `System.getProperty("os.name")` of my own Windows 7 machine.  I am running a java application directly from the machine from within Eclipse.

The returned value is `"windows vista"`!

Seems wrong, very wrong.  And yes I am sure that I am  running the app on a windows 7 machine...

Any idea as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 11):

This is a known bug: [Bug ID 6819886](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6819886). It mentions that it's been fixed in among others Java 7(b55) and Java 6u14(b04). So upgrading to the latest should resolve the issue.